# From Ruby to Perl, Post data is disappearing

Tags: ruby, perl, rest, curl, cgi

I'm trying to mimic the following curl command that works perfectly:

```
curl -k -i -d @content.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: applicaztion/json" https://localhost:909/api/authenticateUser
```

I'm mimicking the curl command in Ruby/rails. I'm using the rest-client gem. The target is an API written in old-style Perl. The problem is that the API does NOT "see" the payload that is sent in the new ruby code:

```
pload = '<string>'.to_json
response = RestClient::Request.execute(url: 'https://localhost:909/api/authenticateUser', method: :post, payload: pload, accept: :json, content_type: :json, verify_ssl: false)
```

What is going wrong? Is my Ruby code bad or is the Perl code "too stupid/old" to pick up the payload from ruby. This is the Perl code:

```
my $data = $cgi->param('POSTDATA') || "";
```

I tend to think the problem is with my ruby code since the old Perl code receives the payload properly from the curl command above and from some other old Perl code.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you looked at the request that cUrl generates compared to the one that Ruby is generating?

Comment: Are you actually sending Accept: applica**z**tion/json with your curl, or was the mistake made when copying it into SO?

Comment: `curl -d` strips out carriage returns and newlines from the data it posts, perhaps the server is depending on all of the data being on a single line, somehow?

Answer (score 1):

For `POSTDATA` to be populated,

1. The request must have a Content-Length header
2. The value of the request's Content-Length header must be non-zero.
3. The request method must be `POST`.
4. The request must have a Content-Type header.
5. The value of the request's Content-Type header must not include any of the following:

   - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
   - multipart/form-data
   - application/xml
   - multipart/related

Comment: I'm not explicitly putting "content-length", I think it is a safe assumption that the rest client is doing that behind the scenes. The request method is post. The Content-Type is "application/json" (same as in curl).